# My JSON writer is only writing one object from my simulation?

Tags: json, unity-game-engine, save

I am trying to get my WriteData() function to save information about multiple objects in the scene in a JSON format. However, the issue I am facing, is that my writer is only saving the initial coordinates of one cell that makes up my floor, rather than saving all coordinates of the floor.

I currently have prefabs with tags, which I am finding and storing into a gameobject array. Then using a foreach loop to go through each game object array to get the relevant information to assign it to the data in the serializable class that I have created, then append it into JSON file. In this process, it is also saving the data as individual JSON strings and not a concatenated string.

This is my first time ever using JSON / Unity's JSON Utility, so any help would be appreciated.

Below the relevant parts of my script I am using currently to do this.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    //used to calculate the rate at which data is collected and written to file
    public float sampleRate = 1f;

    //name of the file when writing data
    string fileName;

    SaveData saveData;      //save data class object 

    //fields for retrieving the data about dynamic humans in the scene
    GameObject[] dynamicHumanTarget;
    string newDynamicHumanId;
    Vector3 newDynamicHumanPosition = new Vector3();
    Vector3 newDynamicHumanRotation = new Vector3();

    //fields for retrieving the data about static humans in the scene;
    GameObject[] staticHumanTarget;
    string newStaticHumanId;
    Vector3 newStaticHumanPosition = new Vector3();
    Vector3 newStaticHumanRotation = new Vector3();

    //fields for retrieving the data about static humans in the scene;
    GameObject[] staticObjectTarget;
    string newStaticObjectId;
    Vector3 newStaticObjectPosition = new Vector3();
    Vector3 newStaticObjectRotation = new Vector3();

    //fields for retrieving the data about the target in the scene;
    GameObject[] targets;
    string newTargetId;
    Vector3 newTargetPosition = new Vector3();
    Vector3 newTargetRotation = new Vector3();

    //fields for retrieving the data about the target in the scene;
    GameObject[] rooms;
    //string newWallId;
    IntVector2 newRoomCoordinates = new IntVector2();



    //called before the simulation is executed
    void Start()
    {
        fileName = "/SimulationData_" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy_hh-mm-ss") + ".json";
        saveData = new SaveData();

        dynamicHumanTarget = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("DynamicHuman");
        staticHumanTarget = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("StaticHuman");
        staticObjectTarget = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("StaticObject");
        targets = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Target");
        rooms = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Cell");
    }

    //called to update the simulation 
    void Update()
    {
        GetDynamicHumanData();
        GetStaticHumanData();
        GetStaticObjectData();
        GetTargetData();
        GetWallData();
        StartWriter();
    }

    public void WriteData()
    {
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + fileName;
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            File.WriteAllText(path, "");
        }

        //robot
        saveData.robotID = robotInstance.robotID;
        saveData.robotPosition = robotInstance.transform.position;
        saveData.robotRotation = robotInstance.transform.eulerAngles;

        //dynamic humans
        saveData.dynamicHumanId = newDynamicHumanId;
        saveData.dynamicHumanPosition = newDynamicHumanPosition;
        saveData.dynamicHumanRotation = newDynamicHumanRotation;

        ///static humans
        saveData.staticHumanId = newStaticHumanId;
        saveData.staticHumanPosition = newStaticHumanPosition;
        saveData.staticHumanRotation = newStaticHumanRotation;

        //static objects
        saveData.staticObjectId = newStaticObjectId;
        saveData.staticObjectPosition = newStaticObjectPosition;
        saveData.staticObjectRotation = newStaticObjectRotation;

        //room objects
        saveData.roomCoordinates = newRoomCoordinates;


        string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(saveData);
        Debug.Log(json);
        File.AppendAllText(path, json);
    }

    void GetWallData()
    {
        foreach (GameObject room in rooms)
        {
            // newWallId = room.GetComponent<MazeWall>().id;
            newRoomCoordinates = room.GetComponent<MazeCell>().coordinates;
        }
    }

    void GetTargetData()
    {
        foreach (GameObject target in targets)
        {
            newTargetId = target.GetComponent<Target>().id;
            newTargetPosition = target.transform.position;
            newTargetRotation = target.transform.eulerAngles;
        }

    }


    void GetStaticObjectData()
    {
        foreach (GameObject staticObject in staticObjectTarget)
        {
            newStaticObjectId = staticObject.GetComponent<StaticObject>().id;
            newStaticObjectPosition = staticObject.transform.position;
            newStaticObjectRotation = staticObject.transform.eulerAngles;
        }
    }


    void GetStaticHumanData()
    {
        foreach (GameObject staticHuman in staticHumanTarget)
        {
            newStaticHumanId = staticHuman.GetComponent<StaticHuman>().id;
            newStaticHumanPosition = staticHuman.transform.position;
            newStaticHumanRotation = staticHuman.transform.eulerAngles;
        }
    }


    void GetDynamicHumanData()
    {
        foreach (GameObject dynamicHuman in dynamicHumanTarget)
        {
            newDynamicHumanId = dynamicHuman.GetComponent<DynamicHuman>().id;
            newDynamicHumanPosition = dynamicHuman.transform.position;
            newDynamicHumanRotation = dynamicHuman.transform.eulerAngles;

        }
    }

    //start the data writer and repeatedly invoke it based on the sample rate
    public void StartWriter()
    {
        InvokeRepeating("WriteData", 0, 1 / sampleRate);
    }

    //stops the data writer
    public void StopWriter()
    {
        CancelInvoke();
    }
}
```

```
    [System.Serializable]
    public class SaveData
    {
        //room positions       
        public IntVector2 roomCoordinates;

        //target position
        public string targetId;
        public Vector3 targetPosition;
        public Vector3 targetRotation;

        //static objects e.g chairs
        public string staticObjectId;
        public Vector3 staticObjectPosition;
        public Vector3 staticObjectRotation;

        //static humans
        public string staticHumanId;
        public Vector3 staticHumanPosition;
        public Vector3 staticHumanRotation;


        //dynamic humans
        public string dynamicHumanId;
        public Vector3 dynamicHumanPosition;
        public Vector3 dynamicHumanRotation;


        //robot data
        public string robotID;
        public Vector3 robotPosition;
        public Vector3 robotRotation;

    }
```

Example Snippet of my JSON file:

```
{
    "roomCoordinates": {
        "x": 2,
        "z": 2
    },
    "targetId": "",
    "targetPosition": {
        "x": 0.0,
        "y": 0.0,
        "z": 0.0
    },
    "targetRotation": {
        "x": 0.0,
        "y": 0.0,
        "z": 0.0
    },
    "staticObjectId": "Chair",
    "staticObjectPosition": {
        "x": 0.5,
        "y": 0.0,
        "z": 1.5
    },
    "staticObjectRotation": {
        "x": 0.0,
        "y": 0.0,
        "z": 0.0
    },
    "staticHumanId": "StaticHuman",
    "staticHumanPosition": {
        "x": -1.5,
        "y": 0.0,
        "z": -4.5
    },
    "staticHumanRotation": {
        "x": 0.0,
        "y": 0.0,
        "z": 0.0
    },
    "dynamicHumanId": "DynamicHuman",
    "dynamicHumanPosition": {
        "x": -1.149653673171997,
        "y": 0.10249999165534973,
        "z": 3.8513429164886476
    },
    "dynamicHumanRotation": {
        "x": 0.0,
        "y": 40.97020721435547,
        "z": 0.0
    },
    "robotID": "Robot",
    "robotPosition": {
        "x": 2.5047712326049806,
        "y": 0.07088841497898102,
        "z": -3.4777321815490724
    },
    "robotRotation": {
        "x": 359.7475891113281,
        "y": 359.37066650390627,
        "z": -0.003071203362196684
    }
}{
    "roomCoordinates": {
        "x": 2,
        "z": 2
    },
    "targetId": "",
    "targetPosition": {
        "x": 0.0,
        "y": 0.0,
        "z": 0.0
    },
    "targetRotation": {
        "x": 0.0,
        "y": 0.0,
        "z": 0.0
    },
    "staticObjectId": "Chair",
    "staticObjectPosition": {
        "x": 0.5,
        "y": 0.0,
        "z": 1.5
    },
    "staticObjectRotation": {
        "x": 0.0,
        "y": 0.0,
        "z": 0.0
    },
    "staticHumanId": "StaticHuman",
    "staticHumanPosition": {
        "x": -1.5,
        "y": 0.0,
        "z": -4.5
    },
    "staticHumanRotation": {
        "x": 0.0,
        "y": 0.0,
        "z": 0.0
    },
    "dynamicHumanId": "DynamicHuman",
    "dynamicHumanPosition": {
        "x": -0.9079896807670593,
        "y": 0.1025000512599945,
        "z": 4.286510944366455
    },
    "dynamicHumanRotation": {
        "x": 0.0,
        "y": 20.490304946899415,
        "z": 0.0
    },
    "robotID": "Robot",
    "robotPosition": {
        "x": 2.4922380447387697,
        "y": 0.07088327407836914,
        "z": -3.2451395988464357
    },
    "robotRotation": {
        "x": 359.7496032714844,
        "y": 357.0594177246094,
        "z": 359.7879638671875
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont understand, as you only have 1  item in each of static humans, dynamichumans, stattkc objects etc how did you expect there to be more than one of each?

Comment: In my scene, I am instantiating 2 static humans, 2 dynamic humans, 2 chairs etc. These all have tags associated with them. So I am trying to use Unity;s FindObjectsWithTag() function to collect and store them into a GameObject array.

Comment: but your save data structure only has 1 of each, eg  `public string staticObjectId; public Vector3 staticObjectPosition; public Vector3 staticObjectRotation;` so there can only be 1 id, 1 position and 1 rotation for the 1 item..

Comment: Oh right I see what your saying. How would I change the save data structure to be able to save multiple object's information. Is there a way to do this with Unity's JSON utility.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to BugFinder's hint, you need to wrap arrays, because the json utility does not support arrays, see this:

> https://answers.unity.com/questions/1123326/jsonutility-array-not-supported.html

So you can loop through your humans, robots, targets, objects, etc,  and add them to a n array, then wrap the array into your SaveData object. More info;

> https://forum.unity.com/threads/json-utility-save-and-load-a-list.488263/#post-3185216

Comment: Thanks I will look into this and get back to this, for any issues.

Comment: In the first link you provided, could you explain what the code ' void ParseJsonToObject(string json)
 {
     var wrappedjsonArray = JsonUtility.FromJson<MyWrapper>(json);
 } ' is doing / how are you meant to use it for what I am trying to do.

Comment: theres also the new json package in unity which is i think the newtonsoft one, it does support arrays

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yes when I used newtonsoft json.net. I managed to figure out how to do it.